# FOREIGN KEY doesn't work

Tags: mysql

Can you help me to add foreign keys to my tables?

My tables:

`_products` table:

```
id_product primary index
code index
```

`_extras` table:

```
id_extra primary index
code
name
```

`_extra_default` table:

```
id_default primary index
product
extra
```

I tried that, but It doesn't working:

```
ALTER TABLE _extra_default FOREIGN KEY (product) REFERENCES _products(code)
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: How when I wanted to create a record in the _extra_default table, I can't select value for the product field from the _products table. So I think I couldn't create the FOREIGN KEY. :(

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
ALTER TABLE _extra_default
ADD constraint c1 FOREIGN KEY (product) REFERENCES _products(code)
```

Comment: Yeah, both of the fields are has the VARCHAR(100) type.